# Nginx normalize redirect ends in permission denied for /

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx, normalization, vhosts

I can't find the source of my normalization error when trying both redirects with www and non-www domain like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name    www.aws.mikeg.de;
    rewrite        ^/(.*) http://aws.mikeg.de/$1 permanent;
    return         301 http://aws.mikeg.de$request_uri;
}
```

All folder an file permissions I checked twice. What I am confused about is that the redirect to the www.Subdomain works while the reverse redirect to non-www doesn't. Here is my full nginx config:

```
user     www-data www-data;
worker_processes    1;

pid    /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections     1024;
}


http {
include        mime.types;
include        fastcgi.conf;
default_type    application/octet-stream;

log_format     main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

log_format    cache '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" nocache:$skip_cache '
        '$upstream_cache_status';

access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
error_log    /var/log/nginx/error.log;

sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout    65;
tcp_nodelay        on;

server_names_hash_bucket_size  128;

# Use gzip compression
# gzip_static        on;  # Uncomment if you compiled Nginx using --with-http_gzip_static_module
gzip            on;
gzip_vary        on;
gzip_proxied        any;
gzip_comp_level    6;
gzip_buffers        16 8k;
gzip_http_version    1.1;
gzip_types        text/plain text/css text/javascript text/xml application/json application/x-javascript application/xml application/xm$ application/xml+rss image/png image/gif image/jpeg;
gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

# Fast-CGI cache
fastcgi_cache_path        /var/cache/nginx/wordpress levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key        "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale    error timeout invalid_header http_500;

add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name    www.aws.mikeg.de;
    #rewrite        ^/(.*) http://aws.mikeg.de/$1 permanent;
    return        301 http://aws.mikeg.de$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen        80 default_server;
    server_name    aws.mikeg.de 54.194.222.209;
    root        /srv/wordpress/;
    index        index.php;

    # Turned off since W3 Total Cache will handle caching
    # and mod_pagespeed won't enhance WP: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-w3-total-cache-googles-mod_pagespeed-and-w3
    pagespeed Off;

    # Include nginx.conf made by W3 Total Cache
    include /srv/wordpress/nginx.conf;

    access_log        /var/log/nginx/wordpress.log cache;
    error_log        /var/log/nginx/wordpress.error.log;

    rewrite_log        on;

    # Set a variable to work around the lack of nested conditionals
    set    $cache_uri $request_uri;

    set $skip_cache 0;

    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|\/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail)\.php|wp\-comments\-popup\.php|wp\-links\-opml\.php|wp\-locations\.php") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    } 

    # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    location ~ /purge(/.*) {
        fastcgi_cache_purge WORDPRESS "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
    }    

    location / {
        # Use cached or actual file if they exists, otherwise pass request to WordPress
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;

        # SECURITY
        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
            return 444;
        }

        # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
        if ($request_method = POST) {
            set $skip_cache 1;
        }

        # this serves static files that exist without running other rewrite tests
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            expires 30d; break;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_cache        WORDPRESS;
        fastcgi_cache_valid    200 60m;
        include            fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info        ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have    "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        fastcgi_pass        unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param        SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

        fastcgi_cache_bypass    $skip_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache    $skip_cache;

        # Note: fastcgi_index is not needed is standard PHP location ~ \.php$ is useed: http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/01/no-input-file-specified-with-php-and-nginx/
     }    

    # Rewrites fpr category base

    # SECURITY
    # Deny access to hidden files
    location ~* /\. {
        deny            all;
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found        off;
    }

    # Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # Deny access to system files in root
    location ~ /(\.|wp-config.php|liesmich.html|readme.html) {
        return 444;
    }

    # Allow access to favicon and robots.txt
    location = /(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt) {
        allow            all;
        log_not_found        off;
        access_log        off;
    }

    # Only recommended when wordpress comments are disabled
    #location ~ /(\.|wp-config.php|liesmich.html|readme.html|xmlrpc.php|wp-comments-post.php) {
        #return 444
    #}
}
}
```

EDIT: Got it … my provider messed up th eDNS settings. The nginx config works pritty fine.

Comment: I like that first redirect from www.aws.mikeg.de to the sub-domain. At first couldn't wrap my head around it but then I guess it makes sense that people would try to stick the www even in front of a sub-domain. Nice.-

Comment: Hi NickNo,

thanks a lot. Anyway this configuration is not in use anymore by myself. I have updated my tutorial yesterday by coincidence: http://mikeg.de/project/cloud-nginx-server-wordpress/

What I am looking for is the piece of Nginx configuration which tells the server not to listen to every fantasy subdomain. My server could be reached by whatever Sub-Domain you enter. Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: Yeh, I do. Make a default location block return a 404 error, and then declare location blocks for each of the sub-domains you have. All other sub-domains will fall back to the default and get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your default server block to catch and reject all traffic to locations that aren't explicitly defined.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    deny all;
}
```